# Smooth goto anchor after load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website and when some contact form is sent, the page is reloaded and some "Successful" message shows up so I can place any script there.

I need the page to auto scroll to an anchor because the contact form is in the footer and it is not visible when reloading and showing the "Successful" message.

So I would need a script which scrolls to an anchor on reloading.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add some code to your questions, or even better a fiddle.

You can use jQuery

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#id_anchor").offset().top},'slow');
```

I hope this is what you're looking for and it helps :)

Sources:

- http://api.jquery.com/offset/
- http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: can this be triggered on load? I'm not a coder obvious :|

Comment: You said "I can place any script I'd like there." So you can place this line of code (changing the id of the anchor) in your after loading js code.

Comment: I got it! window.onload = function() { } THANKS it works